# Not able to restrict user to enter more than 8 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi following is my loginform in that I want to restrict user from entering 8 characters in userName field but it is not working following is my code:

```
<div data-role="content">

        <form id="loginForm">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
                <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"
                    name="username" id="username" value=""   maxlength="8" /> <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" /> <label
                    for="dob">Date of birth:</label> <input type="password"
                    type="password" name="dob" id="dob" value="" />
            </div>
            <div >
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a" >
                    <div class="ui-block-a" >
                        <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Login"
                            id="submitButton">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <input type="reset" data-role="button" value="Cancel"
                            id="cancelButton">
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#username").live('keydown', function (event)
        {

            if ((event.keyCode.length>8))
            {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        }); 

    </script>
```

But still user can enter any number of characters in UserName field. what's wrong in this code? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use maxlength property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `maxlength` to the input field.. instead of using script to restrict.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""  maxlength="8" />
```

Comment: +1, Hey Vega, long time no see, OP have `maxlength` attribute in his markup :)

Comment: @Vega after adding maxlength="8" as edited in my orignal question still user can enter any number of character, and one more thing I am running this code for jquery mobile will it affect this? Because [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H8Zbq/59/) it works perfect for 4 characters but not in my application.

Comment: @Raminson Thanks.. I swear it was not there in his initial post :)

Comment: @Raminson yes it was not there in initial post I had added that later.

Comment: @PPD Do you know how the user is entering.. maxlength should work fine.. I am not sure why/how it is failing for you.

Comment: What a silly mistake I had made, actually by mistake I have 2 login.html files and changes had done in another file therefore it was not working. Thank you all for giving me proper solution

Answer (score 4):

For what do you need javascript ? Simply add the `maxlength` attribute to your input field.

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="8" />
```

simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function countChars(countfrom,displayto) {
    var val = document.getElementById(countfrom).value;

    val = val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/igm, "");

    var len = val.length;

    document.getElementById(displayto).innerHTML = len;
   

    onkeydown = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 9 && e.keyCode != 13 && e.keyCode != 16 && e.keyCode != 17 &&
            e.keyCode != 18 && e.keyCode != 19 && e.keyCode != 20 && e.keyCode != 27 && e.keyCode != 33 && e.keyCode != 34 &&
            e.keyCode != 35 && e.keyCode != 36 && e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 39 && e.keyCode != 40 &&
            e.keyCode != 45 && e.keyCode != 91 && e.keyCode != 92 && e.keyCode != 93 && e.keyCode != 112 && e.keyCode != 113 &&
            e.keyCode != 114 && e.keyCode != 115 && e.keyCode != 116 && e.keyCode != 117 && e.keyCode != 118 && e.keyCode != 119 &&
            e.keyCode != 120 && e.keyCode != 121 && e.keyCode != 122 && e.keyCode != 123 && e.keyCode != 144 && e.keyCode != 145
            && len >= 8)<!-- change the value of len to the number of characters required-->
            e.preventDefault();

    }

}
</script>
```

```html
<h1>Day-3 Task-1</h1>

<br /><h2>Counting Number of Characters with Elimination of Special Charecters</h2>

<textarea id="data" cols="40" rows="5"
onkeyup="countChars('data','charcount');" onkeydown="countChars('data','charcount');" onmouseout="countChars('data','charcount');"></textarea><br>
<span id="charcount">0</span> Characters entered.
```